# BufferedReader includes newline, can't parse the string into numeric

Tags: java, input, io, bufferedreader, java-io

This is the method I use to simplify getting input using BufferedReader, my input is "10 12\n" the rest of the code uses the return value of this function in `Integer.parseInt(//return value)` and is able to do so with the value "10" however it gets a `NumberFormatException` with 12, because the newline is included.

I don't understand how it gets included when I specifically put an `if`-statement before `append()`.

```
private static String getInput(BufferedReader br) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    char x = 0;
    try {
        x = (char) br.read();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    while (x != ' ' && x != '\n' && x != -1) {
        if (x != ' ' && x != '\n' && x != -1)
            sb.append(x);
        try {
            x = (char) br.read();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return (sb.length() == 0) ? null : sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Are the characters "backslash" and "n" (`\\\` and `n`) present, making it look like a newline character `\n`?

Comment: @rgettman no its definitely '\n' cause when i trimmed the string, there's no error and '\n' isn't visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read it all into a String, then call `trim()`, then parse the String.

Alternately, you can use `Character.isLetterOrDigit(x)` to validate your input `char x`.

Comment: thanks! it doesn't receive the error now but why does it include the '\n' when i specifically put a conditional statement not to include it?

Comment: I don't know. Are you certain it's the `\n` you're receiving, that's failing to evaluate?  You can try `Character.isLetterOrDigit(x)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `Scanner` ?  It handles whitespace for you and can even wrap a `Reader`.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner( br);

while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
  int myInt = scanner.nextInt();
}
//should probably put close in a finally block
scanner.close();
```

Comment: oh because im solving UVA problems and Scanner slows it down which will cause it not to be accepted by the judge